# Deleting subtrees in hierarchical agreggates

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I am working on a file-system-like application where I use CQRS/event-sourcing to handle the state of folders and files (creating, moving, renaming, etc). Each node (folder or file) is represented by a single aggregate (as they are standalone unit with own ID). Now I am about to implement deleting of the nodes, where the system is capable, of course, deleting a whole subtree of nodes (= delete a folder containing other folders and files).

Now I quite don't know how to handle this in CQRS style because the command, as I learned, should operate on a single aggregate.

One idea I had is to create a saga which would be created by FolderDeleteStarted event and the responsibility of the saga would be to create commands for each of the child nodes, resulting in cascading creation of sagas for each child folder. Saga would ensure to delete the parent folder once all the commands for child folders would be finished, so it would be blocking. Saga would run in separate thread so the initial command for deleting folder will be still async.

However I don't really like the idea of cascading sagas.

I am new to CQRS and still learning the basics. I would love to know how you would solve similar situation.

Comment: Are your files part of your aggregate (aggregate has ownership) or is your aggregate processed as a result of what happens to the file structure (downstream event processor)?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but Folder aggregate doesn't know about it's children (no ownership is persisted there), everything is "computed" in event handlers into the read model. Thus I cannot send events for deleting each child node from the Folder aggregate, it doesn't know them (this however could be my bad interpretation of the solution to the domain).

Comment: It sounds like you will have to get the read model involved to determine children in that case.

Comment: Yes, that's why I would use sagas, where I would retrieve the information I need using read model to dispatch new commands.

Comment: Since your events have the parent node id, and the domain model is loaded from events, then it will be pretty trivial to add it to your domain model. Reading other aggregates for information in your command handler is OK as long as you don't perform an action on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried cascading sagas (actually process managers in this case, but I will retain the saga term below) with some success. It worked like this:

```
aggregate - DeleteNode 1  -> NodeDeleted 1
saga      - NodeDeleted 1 -> child nodes 2, 3
                             DeleteNode 2
                             DeleteNode 3
aggregate - DeleteNode 2  -> NodeDeleted 2
aggregate - DeleteNode 3  -> NodeDeleted 3
saga      - NodeDeleted 2 -> no child nodes
saga      - NodeDeleted 3 -> no child nodes
```

### Problems

- Cycles (e.g. if following links).

  - Make sure they are detected and exit early or infinite loop will happen
  - Might be necessary to enrich the event to include previous deletion paths for detecting cycles in saga
- Multi-parent (via links again).

  - Be prepared to handle that in the aggregate

    - Fail 2nd deletion attempt b/c it's already deleted
    - Your concurrency strategy comes into play here

In my case, I had both of these problems initially. We corrected the data to not have cycles and added a validation to prevent it in the future. However, multi-parent of a child node was a required feature. It caused unnecessary extra commands against the same subnodes. There was still an edge case we hadn't tracked down where the cascade would stop early. It happened less than 10 times a year, and we simply ran a recalculate command on the item to fix it.

### A better way

The above is complicated and has edge cases that might not be covered.

Instead of using a cascading saga, another option is to have your command handler for this use case recursively load all descendant nodes of the node being deleted and record their IDs (do not actually call delete on the child nodes here as that would require a transaction spanning aggregates). Then as part of your delete use case on your aggregate node, pass in the array of all descendant node ids. Your aggregate likely knows its immediate children IDs, but not all descendants.

Then your saga would have enough information to send commands to delete all descendants at once. It would be a different delete command so as not to be recursive, because you already did the recursive work up front when deletion was requested by the user.

```
aggregate DeleteNode 1 [2,3] -> NodeDeleted 1 [2,3]
saga      NodeDeleted 1 [2,3] -> DeleteNodeInternal 3
                                 DeleteNodeInternal 2
aggregate DeleteNodeInternal 3 -> NodeDeletedInternal 3
          DeleteNodeInternal 2 -> NodeDeletedInternal 2
```

**--Update--**

This method above still does not cover the case where nodes are added to descendants of the deleted parent while the saga is still sending delete commands. To cover that, you can keep a tree structure of the deleted nodes in the initial deletion event. Then when the saga tries to delete a node, it sends with it the expected children of that node. When the expected children and actual children don't match, then emit another event for the saga to resolve that situation.

```
aggregate DeleteNode 1 [2,3] -> NodeDeleted 1 [2,3]
saga      NodeDeleted 1 [2,3] -> DeleteNodeInternal 3
                                 DeleteNodeInternal 2
aggregate DeleteNodeInternal 3 [] -> NodeDeletedInternal 3
                                     ChildEscapedDeletion 4
          DeleteNodeInternal 2 [] -> NodeDeletedInternal 2
saga      ChildEscapedDeletion 4 -> DeleteNode 4
```

Comment: Ok, so I am going the (kind of) right way. I do not have any links, so it's a tree strictly speaking. Cascading sagas would then work ok, right? In the second way, would you make the commands for deleting internal nodes blocking? I am curious how this would behave when asyncly deleting the read model for parent sooner than for the it's child.

Comment: If a node cannot be in multiple places in a tree, then yes cascading should work fine. I was thinking the second way would not be blocking. I don't think it would be a crashing problem in most read models, and if it were, then it would be up to the read model updater to handle the event appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches:

- The easy way: Command handler deletes children before parent. Then parent. Then confirm deletion.
- Low (and fixed) latency for deletes: Use a journal. Command handler adds entries in the journal (one for each child) and deletes parent. Then, an asynchronous task, for each entry in the journal:

  1. Get entry (a parent)
  2. Add entries in the journal (one for each child)
  3. Delete entry